# How do I change App name on iTunesconnect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Hi I have an existing app in App store, I would like to update the app name app store, along with a new binary update. However, I could not find the edit button on the Version Summary section in iTunesConnect. Can anybody tell me how can I do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to click on the new version of your app, then you can edit the "Version Information" and change the name.

Comment: Actually, you can change the name by clicking the **Edit** button in the **Metadata and Uploads** section.

Comment: actually, for an existing app, clicking "Edit" in "Metadata and Uploads" doesn't let you change the name

Comment: "Edit" in "Metadata and Uploads" works for me - my app status is 'Prepare for Upload' which might be a factor

Comment: Did you work this out? I have the same thing with prepare for upload app.

Comment: @ZayinKrige You can only change the app's name if you are releasing a new version of the app. You cannot change it on the version that is already published on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is approved, you cannot change the name via the Edit button in Metadata or anywhere else. I think you need to upload a new version and even then I'm not sure that will do the job without some kind of approval.